# How to select specific string from column?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a column which contains some values like this

```
PRODUCT CODE
A099  - Mouse Corded Other                  
X001  - Pointing Devices Family - FP&A Only 
W049A - Video Dualcam Other                 
N029  - Joystick PC Other                   
Y089  - Video Other Other                   
P059  - Gaming Wheels - FP&A Only
```

I want to fetch string or code before `-`. Is this possible ?

So the result set would be something like this

```
A099
X001
W049A
N029
Y089
P059
```

Comment: Yes, [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Use can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(product_code, '^([^ ]+) ', '\1')
```

Or `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(product_code, '^[^ ]+')
```

Comment: REGEXP_SUBSTR(PRODUCT_CODE, '[^-]+')

Comment: @MuhammadAsim . . . It depends on whether there are spaces and whether you want them in the final result.

Comment: I have used TRIM() to remove spaces. it worked fine though.

Answer (score 1):

Use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(product_code, '^\S+')
FROM yourTable;
```

But actually we don't even need to resort to regex here, the base string functions will do just as well:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(product_code, 1, INSTR(product_code, ' ')-1)
FROM yourTable;
```

In general, if you can avoid invoking a regex engine and instead use a simpler option, this can be the way to go.